# listener could not find available handler for requested type of server

Tags: oracle, database, listener

I run Oracle 11g on Red Hat 4 64 bit. Actually I have RAC but one node is down and I work only with up one (connection string point directly to listener of running node).
I run test with not too big loading.
select count(*) from v$sessions gets ~ 200 in maximum loading, but after half minutes I get this error in my logs.
Each time, lsnrctl services show that all is right. It shows one service with one handler. I see nothing in alert.log. This is very strange, I know, and I'm sure that this is an actual alert.log because, I see there other events in actual time.
Most important: I have SESSION parameter set to 600 and PROCESSES set to 400 so this must be enougha...

I not found good solution in Internet.
Some one knows what I can do for solve this?
Thank you very much for ahead.a

Comment: This is output lsnrctl: Connected to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
  Services summary..
  Services "libd" has 1 instance(s)
    Instance "libd1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
      Handler(s):
        "DEDICATED" established: 1441 refused: 0 state: ready
          LOCAL SERVER

Comment: I just spoke with one DBA and he say me very important thing. He say that, that I see very much connections in log of TNS says, that I need to configure the client connection pool. I use .NET 3.5 64 bit on Windows 7. My application use Oracle.DataAccess.dll and NHibernate that I assume use some another dll. So my question is: where I configure this. Whether I need to configure it separately for each dll or I can put it in connection string?